# Why did the man-next-door attempt to kill the family-next-door?

Tags: plot-explanation, dream-house

In the movie [Dream House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_House_%28film%29), near the end its revealed that:

> Its actually the man-next-door (Ann's husband and Chloe's father) who kills the Ward's wife and two daughters. We are shown that he is entering the house carrying two guns and shoots the daughters with them. We are also shown that he tries to kill Ann (his wife) to get the insurance on Chloe.

So why did he try to kill is neighbors? It would have been no use to him (he only would have had to kill his wife to get the insurance). What did he expect from killing the neighbors?

Comment: But I don't get why the children were killed.

Comment: @sarah I think its because he was confused at the moment. He was thinking of killing the wife secretly and when she saw him, he became confused. And please post your question as a new question on the site. :)

Comment: It was not clear to the general public what actually went down with this movie! I thought that the neighbor Ann and Peter might have been having an affair and the bad boy husband found out and killed Peter's family for revenge! Oh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The husband of Ann actually hired someone to kill his own family for the insurance money. The assassin went to the wrong house and killed Peter Wards (Daniel Craig) family instead. He later tries to kill Ann by himself.

Where did you get the synopsis that you posted?

Comment: I posted the synopsis the way I understood it.. And I guess I was wrong :) (I didn't see it was an assassin who came to the house). Anyway thanks a lot for the answer! It really cleared things up a lot..

Answer (score 5):

He wants to kill his wife, but his murderer (who should kill his wife) went to wrong house - he made mistake.

At the end, he wants to fix everything by killing his wife and neighbour (Ward) too, because everybody thought that Ward is crazy killer - and because he is crazy, he could kill whoever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I chose the other answer because its much clearer and you have not mentioned about an assassin.. But thanks anyway!

Comment: By murderer I meant assassin - my english isn't so good :D

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Now its a lot more clearer! Thanks again for the answer.. :)